# Implicit system calls in UNIX commands

Tags: system-calls

I've been studying UNIX and system calls and I came across a low-level and tricky questions. The question asks what system calls are called for this command:

```
grep word1 word2 > file.txt
```

I did some research and I was unable to find a huge number of resources on the underlying UNIX calls.

However, it seems to me that the answer would be `open` (to open and the file descriptor for the file `file.txt`), then `dup2` (to change the `STDOUT` of `grep` to the file descriptor of `open`), then `write` to write the `STDOUT` of `grep` (which is now the file descriptor of `file.txt`), and finally `close()`, to close the file descriptor of `file.txt`...

However, I have no idea if I am right or on the correct path, can anyone with experience in UNIX enlighten me on this topic?

Comment: Search the site with tag `strace` http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux, you have [`strace`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace):

```
strace -f sh -c 'grep word1 file > file.txt'
```

Here we use `-f` to tell `strace` to trace child process.

In *BSD, you have [`dtruss`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtruss.1m.html) (which use [`dtrace`](https://wiki.freebsd.org/DTrace) underlying):

```
dtruss -f sh -c 'grep word1 file > file.txt'
```

OSX has [`trace`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/trace.1.html). Historical Unix systems have [truss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truss_(Unix)) ([Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/truss-1.html), [AIX](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/truss.htm), etc.).

Comment: In the case of OpenBSD, where dtruss/dtrace is not available, there is `ktrace` -- which is also available on the other *BSDs.